# ngx-google-places-autocomplete - Track address not changed event

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, autocomplete, ngx-google-places-autocomplete

**html**

```
<input
  matInput
  ngx-google-places-autocomplete
  [options]="options"
  #placesRef="ngx-places"
  (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)"
  formControlName="addressString"
  required"/>
```

**TS**

```
public handleAddressChange(address: any) {}
```

Whenever we select an address from google autocomplete list *"handleAddressChange"* event get executed, but when we input any value not from the autocomplete list this event *"handleAddressChange"* is not triggering.
We want to capture this event in which we haven't selected any value from autocomplete.
How can we achieve that ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks